# Mask UIView Touch Detect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiview

[image: i get this view after masking.View size is 310 width 310 height.i just want to detect toch on black Area]I have a big Frame through which i masked a smaller view
now i want to detect just smaller one but touches began did not allow me to filter masked view
any pointers ?

Comment: u have sub view in to main View??

Comment: a picture would be nice, or just a better explanation..

Comment: i get this view after masking.View size is 310 width 310 height.i just want to detect touch on black Area

Comment: what u  are trying actually..?

Comment: i want to implement non rectangular Frames. i choose masking for that but not able to detect touch on just masked view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UIviewTapped:)];
 [yourUIview addGestureRecognizer:gr];

}

-(void) UIviewTapped:(UIView *)view
{

  // write touched code here. 

}
```

Comment: touch detected on non black Area too ..

Comment: I just want to detect touch on black Area .. not on white one .. View Frame is 310x310 ... i want to become able to get touches detection on just black view

Comment: @user1780632- what is mask ??? i mean it is UIImgeView,image,..etc.?? wtever it is. just replace it with yourUIview in my code. write mask_obj instand of yourUIview..

Comment: we cant add the gestures on layers