# UIViews-masked-off-area-still-touchable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, image-masking

[image: Masked image]

I have Masked UIView . View with blue dots. Green circle Area is masked off.I dont want to get touches on that area.i just want to get touches on visible layer of the View.

Comment: didn't you just ask the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382667/mask-uiview-touch-detect

Comment: i did not find answer there

Comment: Then edit your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a CGPath of the masked area & then check if the touch falls in ur masked area or not like this :

UIBezierPath *p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:myCGPath];

BOOL isInPath = [p containsPoint:myCGPoint];

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: how can i make CGPath of the masked Area ?

Comment: how u r masking the UIView ??

Comment: hmm ... i thought like you will be using path to mask the UIView. Let me see.

Answer (score 1):

Please select touch view in your touch method in place of self.view

May be it helps

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: i am masking Myview whose frame is cgrectmake(0, 0 , 310,310);